# loading a trained model back into tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have constructed a model in Tensorflow, which I've trained. Now I want to work with the outputs, so I want to load the Checkpoint, Meta and all the other files back into tensorlow.

I have used the following code to train the model:

```
# Logging
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summary_dir + '/train')
test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summary_dir + '/test')
validate_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summary_dir + '/validate')
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summary_dir, sess.graph)
saver = tf.train.Saver()  # for storing the best network

# Initialize variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)

# Best validation accuracy seen so far
bestValidation = -0.1

# Training loop
coord = tf.train.Coordinator() # coordinator for threads
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord = coord, sess=sess) # start queue thread

# Training loop
for i in range(FLAGS.maxIter):
    xTrain, yTrain = sess.run(data_batch)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x_data: xTrain, y_target: np.transpose([yTrain])})
    summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x_data: xTrain, y_target: np.transpose([yTrain])})
    train_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0):
        print("Iteration:", i + 1, "/", FLAGS.maxIter)
        summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x_data: dataTest.data, y_target: np.transpose([dataTest.target])})
        test_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
        currentValidation, summary = sess.run([accuracy, merged], feed_dict={x_data: dataTest.data,
                                                                             y_target: np.transpose(
                                                                                 [dataTest.target])})
    validate_writer.add_summary(summary, i)
    if (currentValidation > bestValidation and currentValidation <= 0.9):
        bestValidation = currentValidation
        saver.save(sess=sess, save_path=FLAGS.summary_dir + '/bestNetwork')
        print("\tbetter network stored,", currentValidation, ">", bestValidation)

coord.request_stop()  # ask threads to stop
coord.join(threads)  # wait for threads to stop
```

Now I want to load the model back into Tensorflow. I want to be able to do a few things:

- Work with the output I've already created for the training and test datasets.
- Load new data to the model, and then be able to use the same weights to make new outputs.

I've tried using the following code to load the model back into tensorflow, but it doesn't work:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(FLAGS.summary_dir + '/bestNetwork.meta')
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.summary_dir + '/checkpoint'))
```

I get the following error when running the code:

TypeError: expected bytes, NoneType found

As I've understod, I'm loading the meta graph from the previous section with the tf.train.import_meta_graph() function, and then I load the weights with the checkpoint part. So why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

You saved the model as `bestNetwork`.  Try this instead:

```
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.summary_dir + '/**bestNetwork**'))
```